# Storing Chat Log on AWS DynamoDB?

Tags: amazon-web-services, chat, amazon-dynamodb

I am thinking of building a chat app with AWS DynamoDB. The app will support 1:1 and group chats.

I want to create one table for each one of the chats, where there is a record for each sent chat text line. Is DynamoDB suitable for this kind of job?

I am also thinking of merging both tables. But is this a good idea, if there are – let's assume – 100k or 1000k users?

Answer (score 1):

I think you may run into problems with the read capacity on your table. The write capacity should be ok, as there are not so many messages coming in per second (e.g. 10 or so), but you'll need to constantly read from it for all users, so that'll be expensive.

If you want to use DynamoDB just as storage and distribute the chat messages like in any normal chat over the network, then it may make sense, depending on your use cases. You could, assuming you have a hash key UserId and Timestamp, query all messages from a specific user during a specific period as a result. If you want, however, search within the chat text (a much more useful feature, probably), then DynamoDB won't work per se. It's not like SQL, where you could do a `LIKE '%abc%'` query (which isn't a good idea in SQL either).

Probably you're better off using S3 as data storage and ElasticSearch as search instrument. If you require the aforementioned use case "get all messages from user X in timespan S" (as a simple example) you could additionally use DynamoDB to store metadata, such as UserId, Timestamp, PositionInFile or something like that.

Comment: Thanks. How would I store it on S3? As a file for each chat?

Comment: Honestly, I am not sure, but it sounds reasonable to store a file per chat and maybe also per day. Like this, to get the first screen, you just load the current day of conversation from the file.

Comment: Not sure S3 is helpful, but i agree DynamoDB will not be a good option to do this kind of stuff

Comment: Ok, thank you for this valueable information. I think I will try to install a XMPP server on AWS instead.

Comment: @HarshalBulsara S3 may not be the right choice for everything, but for example HipChat is doing it that way (although probably with ElasticSearch, etc. on top), afaik. Metadata, such as users, references to objects (not the objects themselves), and so on, should, of course, be stored in a database, but the actual chat contents don't have to be.

Comment: @MJQZ1347, if you don't mind me asking, what did you end up deciding?

Comment: @MJQZ1347 I am curious too as well

Comment: Sorry guys, I switched to Firebase when they introduced version 3 in May. Didn't experiment with AWS any longer after that.